# Swagger yaml/yml oneOf does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, swagger

I'm currently building our REST API, and I am stuck when implementing our File Type. A File can be either from a User or a Group, I tried this with `oneOf` but I'm getting an Error. Here is my Code and the Error:

```
File:
  type: object
  properties:
    owner:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: "#/definitions/User"
        - $ref: "#/definitions/Group"
      description: Owner of the File
```

The Error:

```
swagger_spec_validator.common.SwaggerValidationError: ("'oneOf' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'\n\nFailed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema['properties']['definitions']['additionalProperties']['properties']['properties']['additionalProperties']:\n    {'additionalProperties': False,\n     'description': 'A deterministic version of a JSON Schema object.',\n     'patternProperties': {'^x-': {'$ref': '#/definitions/vendorExtension'}},\n     'properties': {'$ref': {'type': 'string'},\n                    'additionalProperties': {'anyOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/schema'},\n                                                       {'type': 'boolean'}],\n                                             'default': {}},\n             'allOf': {'items': {'$ref': '#/definitions/schema'},\n                              'minItems': 1,\n                              'type': 'array'},\n                    'default': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/default'},\n                    'description': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/description'},\n                    'discriminator': {'type': 'string'},\n                    'enum': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/enum'},\n                    'example': {},\n                    'exclusiveMaximum': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/exclusiveMaximum'},\n                    'exclusiveMinimum': {'$ref':'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/exclusiveMinimum'},\n                    'externalDocs': {'$ref': '#/definitions/externalDocs'},\n                    'format': {'type': 'string'},\n                    'items': {'anyOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/schema'},\n                                        {'items': {'$ref': '#/definitions/schema'},\n                                         'minItems': 1,\n                                         'type': 'array'}],\n               'default': {}},\n                    'maxItems': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/definitions/positiveInteger'},\n                    'maxLength': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/definitions/positiveInteger'},\n                    'maxProperties': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/definitions/positiveInteger'},\n                    'maximum': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/maximum'},\n          'minItems': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/definitions/positiveIntegerDefault0'},\n                    'minLength': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/definitions/positiveIntegerDefault0'},\n        'minProperties': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/definitions/positiveIntegerDefault0'},\n                    'minimum': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/minimum'},\n                    'multipleOf': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/multipleOf'},\n                    'pattern': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/pattern'},\n                    'properties': {'additionalProperties': {'$ref': '#/definitions/schema'},\n                                   'default': {},\n                                   'type': 'object'},\n                    'readOnly': {'default': False, 'type': 'boolean'},\n                    'required': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/definitions/stringArray'},\n                    'title': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/title'},\n                    'type': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/type'},\n                    'uniqueItems': {'$ref': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#/properties/uniqueItems'},\n                    'xml': {'$ref': '#/definitions/xml'}},\n     'type': 'object'}\n\nOn instance['definitions']['File']['properties']['owner']:\n    {'description': 'Owner of the File',\n     'oneOf': {'schema': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/User'},\n                          {'$ref': '#/definitions/Group'}]}}", <ValidationError: "'oneOf' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'">)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Sorry for the Format, but this is the Error Message...
When I'm right it fails because of `oneOf` but as described [here](https://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject) `oneOf` it totally usable here.

Please help me fix this, as I'm sitting on this for one Hour now

edit: I'm using Version 2.0 of swagger

Comment: `oneOf` was introduced in OpenAPI 3.0. Is your spec `openapi: 3.0.0` or `swagger: '2.0'`?

Comment: 2.0, but connexion does not support that yet....
Is there a other way of accomplishing that?

Comment: `oneOf` won't work in 2.0.